# How can I fix my localhost or apache configuration?

Tags: wordpress, apache, networking, localhost

I messed around with my httpd install on my Macbook retina while trying to get my website bramchaat.myeffect.net hosted with localhost.run because while trying to use port 8888 with MAMP and SSH through localhost.run's service apache was throwing an error.

Eventually while troubleshooting with help from the creator of localhost.run, I was able to host the site on my iMac on port 80, but while it works on any device, it won't work on my Macbook retina, and I suspect it's because I messed with my computer's apache/httpd settings.

When I try to go to my website while running the localhost.run protocol on my iMac, on my Macbook retina it goes to a 'This site can't be reached' and refused to connect page. For some reason while my site can be reached on any other device, it can't be reached from my Macbook retina.

How can I fix my Macbook's localhost connection or apache configuration so I can reach my website from it? I really will appreciate any help and solution anyone can provide.

EDIT: I tried reinstalling Catalina and it didn't work. If anyone can help, I will seriously appreciate it. I can't think of any options.